# Why does passing wind break wudo when sneezing does not? And why don't we wash our bottoms after passing wind?

Tags: wudu

If passing wind brakes wudo then why sneezing does not, as in case of sneeze one lets out filth while in passing wind one does not pass out any.

If wudo has to be completed again after passing wind then why is one not required to wash his/her bottom?